# Vue - how to access the state within MutationAction

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I can't access the state inside `@MutationAction`

I'm using:

`Nuxt.js v2.13.3` `"vuex-module-decorators": "^0.17.0"`

```js
import { Module, VuexModule, MutationAction } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

@Module({
  name: 'counter',
  stateFactory: true,
  namespaced: true
})
export default class Auth extends VuexModule {
  public counter: number = 5

  @MutationAction({ mutate: ['counter'] })
  async set() {
    console.log(this.counter)
    return { counter }
  }
}
```

output: `undefined`

---

this way it works

```js
@MutationAction({ mutate: ['counter'] })
async set() {
  console.log((this.state as any).counter)
  return { counter }
}
```

output: `5`

---

but if I set a value before reading it, everything goes well

```js
@MutationAction({ mutate: ['counter'] })
async set() {
  this.counter = '20'
  console.log(this.counter)
  return { counter }
}
```

output: `20`

can someone help me make this work? `this.counter`

Answer (score 0):

the returned value is stored

```
@MutationAction({ mutate: ['counter'] })
async set(val) {
  return { counter: val }
}
```